# Intellisense not working for new classes created in Unity

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, reference, intellisense

Unity Version: 2017.2.0f3

Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.4.3

It will not recognize the UnityEngine references, it works sometimes, but now it does not work before. I have tried restarting Unity AND VS.

[image]
[image]